# Set color of appended div based on dropdown selection

Tags: javascript, css

The following code is a snippet of a JavaScript append function:

```
var $newLi = $("<li><div1><img src='" + src + "' id='logo" + counter + "' name='logo" + counter + "'/></div1><div2><input type='text' id='college" + counter + "' name='college" + counter + "' value='" + task + "' readonly/></div2><div4><input type='text' id='sports" + counter + "' name='sports" + counter + "' value='" + sports + "' readonly/></div4><div5><input type='text' id='interest" + counter + "' name='interes" + counter + "' value='" + interest + "' readonly/></div5></li>");
```

The following is the html dropdown list:

```
<form name="newItem" id="newItem">
    <select id="interestresults" required>
        <option value="">Select Level of Interest...</option>
        <option>Low</option>
        <option>Medium</option>
        <option>High</option>
        <option>Extreme</option>
    </select>
    <button type="reset" id="reset">Reset</button>
    <input type="button" id="addItem" value="Add" />
</form>
```

So, essentially, what is happening is a list is being appended on button click and is creating 4 div's. div1, div2, and div4 are of no concern. div5 though is what I am targeting.

div5 is created and displays "interest" text that was selected from a dropdown list and submitted. The interest options are "low", "medium", "high", and "extreme". At the moment, div5 css background is set to green, however, my question is how to set the div5 background color based on which interest option is selected from dropdown list. For example, if low was selected, div5 will be red and if extreme is selected, then div5 will be green.

Full JavaScript here:

```
$("#addItem").click(function() {
            if (maxAppend >= 10) return;
                var task = $('#searchresults').val();
                var sports = $('#sportsresults').val();
                var interest = $('#interestresults').val();

                var src = $('#searchresults').find(":selected").attr('data-src');

                var $newLi = $("<li><div1><img src='" + src + "' id='logo" + counter + "' name='logo" + counter + "'/></div1><div2><input type='text' id='college" + counter + "' name='college" + counter + "' value='" + task + "' readonly/></div2><div4><input type='text' id='sports" + counter + "' name='sports" + counter + "' value='" + sports + "' readonly/></div4><div5><input type='text' id='interest" + counter + "' name='interest" + counter + "' value='" + interest + "' readonly/></div5></li>");
                    $newLi.attr("id", "newLi" + counter++);
            maxAppend++;
                    $("#tasks").append($newLi);

                    $('#searchresults').find(":selected").remove();
                    $('#sportsresults option').prop('selected', function() {
                        return this.defaultSelected;
                    });

                });

        $('#deleteall').click(function(e) {
            $('#tasks').children().last().remove();
        });
    });
```

Comment: where's your dropdown list? You should give us context of all of the code you're referencing so we have a working demo ([mcve]) of what you're working with now.

Comment: edited AGAIN. hopefully that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you skipped documentation on `<select>` tag and its purpose.

The `<select>` tag is used to allow the user to select an `<option>` which sets the `value` of its parent `<select>` to it.

Add `value` attributes to your `<option>` elements and use `$('#interestresults').val()` to get the currently selected value. Here's an arbitrary example, based on what I could make of your current code:

```js
$(document)
  .on('click', '#addItem', function () {
    var ul = $('#results'),
        select = $('#interestresults'),
        color = select.val(),
        text = select.find('option:selected').text();
    if (color && 10 > ul.find('li').length) {
      ul.append($('<li />', {
        text: text,
        style: "background-color:" + color
      }))
    }
  })
  .on('click', '#reset', function () {
    $('#results').html('');
  })
```

```css
#results {
  list-style-type:none;
  color: white;
  padding: 0;
}
#results li {
  padding: .5rem;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.12);
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,.21)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="newItem" id="newItem">
  <select id="interestresults" required>
    <option value="">Select Level of Interest...</option>
    <option value="red">Low</option>
    <option value="orange">Medium</option>
    <option value="blue">High</option>
    <option value="green">Extreme</option>
  </select>
  <button type="reset" id="reset">Reset</button>
  <input type="button" id="addItem" value="Add" />
</form>

<ul id="results">
  
</ul>
```

Comment: when you say "$('#interestresults').val() will return the value of the selected option" how will that allow for me to adjust the css for the individual option selected? Will that not just display the value or text red, orange, blue, or green? Or is value the newly created  \div?

Comment: Are you trying to change the color of the selected option?

Comment: yes, the option that is selected and appended to a list. I do NOT want to change the color of the dropdown list itself. If that makes sense?

Comment: I told you how to get the selected value. Based on that you select the desired target and apply a color to it. For example: `$('#div5').css({color:$('#interestresults').val()})`. How do you expect me to know what selectors to use on a markup you are not showing?

Comment: just saw the snippet you added. when adding the selected option "high" (for example), i want "high" to be displayed upon append, but want the background color to be blue. then if adding "extreme", i want the background color to be green.

Comment: Use the `<>` button and add a working example to your question. Your snippet is taken out of context and doesn't make any sense because it references elements that are nowhere to be found in your markup. Please add a [mcve] to your question. By adding `value` attributes to the `<select>` element's `<option>`s you can use `.val()` method on the select to get the currently selected option's value. This gives you the possibility to use that value in your script's logic and do what you want to do.

Comment: let me see if i can make a fiddle of it